# make a .jar file of a java project(with some classes) in command prompt or Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to create a jar file of a java project. I am using eclipse IDE and maven to make the built. I am trying to execute it through command prompt

Comment: Can you post the commands you are trying and explain what problem you are facing?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to run `mvn package` that will produce a jar file in the artifacts folder and then run `java -jar %YOUR_JAR_FILE%`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `maven-assembly-plugin` in your `pom.xml` if you are looking for an executable jar. Example:

```
<plugins>
    <!-- other plugins -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>PATH_TO_YOUR_MAIN_CLASS</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Then build with maven: `mvn clean install`

Then you can run from command prompt: `java -jar YOUR_JAR_NAME.jar`